# An error occurs when computing a decomposition matrix of a factor group with MAGMA

Tags: magma-cas

I'd like to ask, if anybody can help me with the following:

I entered this in MAGMA, but an error message (see below) appeared.

```
G:=Alt(5);
H:=sub<G|[(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)]>; 
N:=Normaliser(G,H);
H_in_N:=sub<N|H>;
FAC,f:=quo<N|H_in_N>; 
K:=GF(2^4);
dec:=DecompositionMatrix(FAC,K);
```

Now, the following error message is returned:

```
DecompositionMatrix(

G: GrpPerm: G, Degree 3, Order 3,
K: GF(2^4)
)

DecompositionMat(
G: GrpPerm: G, Degree 3, Order 3,
K: GF(2^4)
)
In file ".../Magma/package/RepThry/ModGrp/peakwords.m", 
line 365, column 8:
>>   entry`decomp := sol;
          ^
Runtime error in :=: RHS value invalid for field 'decomp'
>
```

I would be grateful for any hints, how to resolve this. Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: Derek Holt told me that this is indeed a bug (but not a mathematical one) and that it will be fixed...but it may take a while until the patch is exported.